# Efficient SQL querying-bulk data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am looking for something like this: [find n consecutive free numbers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/find-n-consecutive-free-numbers-from-table) but not exactly this.

As a part of performance tuning, I am looking for a better solution which will return only first 10 records from SQL Procedure, when I click on the page index of a datagrid. The total record count will be more than 100 000 but I don’t want to process the whole set each time.

ie. When I click the pageindex "1" it should return records 1-10 whereas for "2"- 11-20 so on..

Comment: If you are using server 2012 it adds `SKIP` and `FETCH` for efficient row skipping. `SELECT * FROM Page ORDER BY SomeColumn OFFSET ((@pageIndex - 1) * @rowsPerPage) ROWS FETCH NEXT(@rowsPerPage) ROWS ONLY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Row_Number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
select columnA, columnB from
(
     select Row_Number() over (order by id) as rowNo, columnA, columnB from yourTable 
)
where rowNo > fromIndex and rowNo < toIndex
```

It's much simpler than the sample you've posted.